# VBA error handling for functions called from a macro

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

In an access database I have a small function that is called on startup that registers a piece of software for generating barcodes.

When the software is not installed then then Microsoft access runtime errors out, So i would like to add some proper error handling that informs the user of what is causing the problem.

This function is called from a macro on startup and is crashing the database rather than the error handling working properly.

Is my error handling incorrect?

```
Public Function LicenseTBarCode()
On Error GoTo Err_LicenceTBarCode

Dim TB As New TBarCode10
TB.LicenseMe "<EXPUNGED>", eLicKindSite, 1, "<EXPUNGED>", eLicProd1D
Set TB = Nothing
Exit Function

Err_LicenceTBarCode:
MsgBox "TBarcode Software is not installed. Please contact the database administrator.", vbExclamation, Error
DoCmd.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: Your error code is okay in a general way, but I suspect the problem is in `Dim TB As New TBarCode10`. This suggests you have created a reference to the relevant library, is this the case?

Comment: Yes, there is a type library which is used. The problem occurs when the library isn't available. 

I had figured that if the libraries could not be found then the it would go to the error handler.

Comment: You should read http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/AccessReferenceErrors.html

Comment: Note that in MS Access, missing references can cause problems that will prevent seemingly unrelated code from running. For the most part, it is recommended that you use late binding.

Comment: I Agree with @Remou here on LateBinding. I had to delete my answer as I had missed the `Dim` Part.

Comment: I had something similar with an application l built.  The solution was based on some code from code library so l cannot post the code.  One of the functions which checks if a reference is valid has this single line of code RefValid = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References(strRefName).IsBroken where strRefName if the name of the reference.  To get the name of reference's in your application this page for how to get the reference name [link](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s204/vbe-references.htm).  Hopefully that should allow you to check if the reference exists.

Comment: This [page](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=46toCUvklIQC&pg=PA947&lpg=PA947&dq=Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.is+broken&source=bl&ots=jmI-3tFIO7&sig=3-FN32Z_Wy4BGZ6e2As7rbVYp94&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WT_WT47-DorT8gOE7K21Dw&ved=0CGcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.is%20broken&f=false) also has some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to use late binding:

```
Public Function LicenseTBarCode()
On Error GoTo Err_LicenceTBarCode

    Dim TB 
    Set TB = CreateObject("TBarCode10.TBarCode10")
    TB.LicenseMe "<EXPUNGED>", eLicKindSite, 1, "<EXPUNGED>", eLicProd1D
    Set TB = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_LicenceTBarCode:
    MsgBox "TBarcode Software is not installed. Please contact the database administrator.", vbExclamation, Error
    DoCmd.Quit
End Function
```

In order for this to work well, you will really need to use late binding for all of your TBarCode code, including any other TBarCode objects you might be using. If you're not already familiar with Late Binding it can be a little challenging to understand at first, especially if you are working with any classes that use the factory pattern.

With late binding, you will uncheck your reference to the DLL and then your code needs to compile without errors. Developing with Late Binding can be challenging since you will not have access to IntelliSense. It works best to develop with Early Binding and then convert your code over to Late Binding later.

Another thing you lose with Late Binding is any constants that were defined in the original object. You have to create these yourself. Depending on how many you need to use and where all you need to use them, it might be simplest to create a module just to hold these constants. You really only need to have the constants that are actually used in your code.

```
Global Const eLicKindSingle = 1 'Single license for exactly one computer
Global Const eLicKindSite = 2 'Site license for an arbitrary number of computers within one site (or one facility) at one legal address
Global Const eLicKindDeveloper = 3 'Developer license for redistribution to 3rd party
Global Const eLicKindWeb = 3 'Web-server license 

Global Const eLicProd1D = 32 '(1D codes)
Global Const eLicProd2D = 33 '(2D codes)
```

Alternately, you can just use the values that the constants contain. For example:

```
TB.LicenseMe "<EXPUNGED>", 2, 1, "<EXPUNGED>", 32
```

Also, to my knowledge Late Binding does not work with ActiveX controls. ActiveX Controls are inherently early bound.

There is another way to handle this problem. I use a "starter" database file that handles some of the prerequisites for the main database. This starter database doesn't use any references. It only checks the file system to see if the correct files are installed. If they are not, it pops up a messagebox with the correct errors/warnings and then it either runs the main database file or chooses not to run it, depending on the logic you've written into it. This is one way to avoid using Late Binding.

Comment: This answer somewhat worked. The database still crashes when the type library is not installed.

Comment: I apologise, I did not have the Reference turned off in the References dialog.

I am accepting this answer